# Can you automatically check if there is a removable disk in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to write a program in batch, which recognizes if you put in a USB stick and then automatically copies a folder. The copying was easy, but I'm struggling with recognizing the USB stick.

I've done this one but what if the USB stick has another letter and there's a hard drive on the letter "E". Also it checks only every 2 minutes. It would be nice if the program could instantly recognize the USB stick.

The code I have tried:

```
@echo off
goto search
:search
IF EXIST E: GOTO E
timeout /T 120 /nobreak
goto search
:F
xcopy /s F:\test\*.* C:\Users\sebas\Desktop\copied\*.*
exit
```

Comment: <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442263/how-can-i-run-a-bat-file-saved-on-my-system-automatically-whenever-any-pendrive/59442307#59442307>how-can-i-run-a-bat-file-saved-on-my-system-automatically-whenever-any-pendrive</a>

Comment: Marks comment provides the answer. 
It doesnt take much to modify the code in the vbs that performs the copy action to Run a batch File if you still wish to use batch.
You could also Create FileSystemObject ForWriting and Write the Drive value to a text file to retrieve with the batch you launch.

Answer (score 0):

USB drives are removable disks, and can be found as follows:

```
Prompt>wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID, Description
Description       DeviceID
Local Fixed Disk  C:
Removable Disk    D:
CD-ROM Disc       E:
Removable Disk    F:
```

Comment: The main issue with the above is that it's not quite correct. Not all USB storage devices are designated as removable disks, and all removable disks are not USB storage devices. This means the code only works on storage devices which have been read by the system to be removable disks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get exactly the removable disks using this:

```
wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, description | find "Removable"
```

Comment: They don't want to get removable disks, they want to get USB storage devices. Not all USB storage devices are designated as removable disks, and all removable disks are not USB storage devices. This means the code only works on logical storage devices which have been read by the system to be removable disks, and actually retrieves all logical devices designated as removable, regardless of whether they use the Universal Serial Bus.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link mark provided, this is How you would store the driveletter into a text file, then launch your batch program.

Include a bit of code in your Batch to recover the drive Letter and apply it to a Variable:

```
<StoreDriveLeterFilepath.txt (
Set /p Drive_Letter=
)
```

Adjust your XCOPY line to make use of the variable.

```
xcopy /s %Drive_Letter%\test\*.* C:\Users\sebas\Desktop\copied\*.*
```

The vbs code modified to store the drive into .txt and launch your Batch program.
Insert your Batch's Filepath where indicated

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set evtDevice = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent")

Wscript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = evtDevice.NextEvent
    'report an event
    Wscript.Echo " Win32_Device Changed event occurred" & VBNewLine
    If objReceivedEvent.EventType = 1 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Config Changed" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 2 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Arrived" 

         Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Volume")
         For Each objItem in colItems
               If objitem.DriveType = 2 then
                        Wscript.Echo objItem.DriveType & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.driveletter

            Dim objFSO 'File System Object
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
            Const ForWriting = 2
            Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("StoreDriveLeterFilepath.txt", ForWriting, True)
            objTS.Write ("objItem.driveletter")
            objTS.Close()
            Set bjFSO = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
            Set objTS = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
            set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell") 
            WshShell.run "Your Batch Filepath Here.bat", 1, true


               End If
        Next


    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 3 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Left" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Computer Docked" 
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Using Marks approach, You don't need the timeout or If exists approach.
The modified Solution above automates the process of Launching your .bat whenever a new drive is Inserted.
It may be worth Including A Choice option In your Batch to allow you to choose whether to proceed with back up when the device is inserted.

There's Merit to Using Batch / Vbs Hybrid for this purpose. You  could have a menu in your batch to make the choice of How and what to back up.

Comment: Further testing has revealed that when an event occurs, Each Connected Usb will be reported, not just the one most recently connected.

Each will be loaded into the batch seprately, oldest connection to newest. The batch is launched anew during each iteration of the loop prior to confirming the message box.

To account for this, Either add a menu option in your batch to select actions once drive letter has been loaded, Or Put in Conditional Checks to Automate what action to take according to the Drive Letter detected.